# Formatting of json objects in Json array with for loop in C

Tags: c, json

I was trying to format a json array and send it to server. I have tried the below code and got correct string output.

```
json_t* json_arr = json_array();
json_t* json_request = json_object();
json_t* json_request1 = json_object();
json_t* host = json_object();
json_t* host1 = json_object();

char *buf;
json_object_set_new(json_request, "mac", json_string("005056BD3B6C"));
json_object_set_new(host, "os_type", json_string("Linux_Fedora"));
json_object_set_new(host, "user_agent", json_string("Wget/1.10.2 (Fedora modified)"));

json_object_set_new(json_request1, "mac", json_string("005056BD3B60"));
json_object_set_new(host1, "os_type", json_string("Linux_Fedora"));
json_object_set_new(host1, "user_agent", json_string("Wget/1.10.2 (Fedora modified)"));

json_object_set_new(json_request ,"host", host);
json_object_set_new(json_request1 ,"host", host1);

json_array_append(json_arr ,json_request);
json_array_append(json_arr ,json_request1);
buf = json_dumps(json_arr ,JSON_PRESERVE_ORDER);
```

Output:

```
[  
   {  
      "mac":"005056BD3B6C",
      "host":{  
         "os_type":"Linux_Fedora",
         "user_agent":"Wget/1.10.2 (Fedora modified)"
      }
   },
   {  
      "mac":"005056BD3B60",
      "host":{  
         "os_type":"Linux_Fedora",
         "user_agent":"Wget/1.10.2 (Fedora modified)"
      }
   }
]
```

---

I wanted to put the above code in loop as per my requirement.so i tried the below code.

```
json_t* json_arr = json_array();
char *buf;
const char *str[3];
str[0] = "005056b4800c";
str[1] = "005056b4801c";
str[2] = "005056b4802c";

for (i=0;i<3;i++)
{
   json_t* json_request = json_object();
   json_t* host = json_object();
   json_object_set_new(json_request, "mac", json_string(str[i]));
   json_object_set_new(host, "os_type", json_string("Linux_Fedora"));
   json_object_set_new(host, "user_agent", json_string("Wget/1.10.2 (Fedora modified)"));
   json_object_set_new(json_request ,"host", host);
   json_array_append(json_arr ,json_request);
   json_decref(json_request);
   json_decref(host);
 }
buf = json_dumps(json_arr ,JSON_PRESERVE_ORDER);
```

Here i got the below buffer value:

```
[  
   {  
      "mac":"005056b4800c",
      "host":{  
         "mac":"005056b4801c",
         "host":{  
            "mac":"005056b4802c",
            "host":{  

            }
         }
      }
   },
   {  
      "mac":"005056b4801c",
      "host":{  
         "mac":"005056b4802c",
         "host":{  

         }
      }
   },
   {  
      "mac":"005056b4802c",
      "host":{  

      }
   }
]
```

How can i use loop and format the array same as above?

Comment: Maybe you want to tell us which JSON library you are using. Is it Jansson?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it looks like you are using Jansson library, you should look at your reference counting.

```
json_object_set_new(json_request ,"host", host);
json_array_append(json_arr ,json_request);
json_decref(json_request);
json_decref(host);
```

`json_object_set_new` "steals" the reference of the added object. This means the reference counter for `host` is not incremented when added to the parent object.
If you manually decrement the counter, the object will be free'd.
This causes an empty/invalid object.

`Host` will be free'd if the outer `json_request` is free'd.

Decrementing the counter for `json_request` is OK because `json_array_append` increments the counter.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I am able to send it in correct format now .